# How to adjust a TLayout to fit the mostBottom

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have just created a descendant class from Tlayout where it contains a calloutPanent in order to use as a sort of messenger so those layouts will be inserted within a ScrollBox well the problem is that I want everytime I insert a instance of this class it should get placed into the mostbottom , I have used

```
layout.align:=TalignLayou.mostBottom;
```

but if I place another it get aligned upon the old one ^^ 
any ideas 
thanks in advance

Comment: This might depend on the current position of the layout. Try first positioning the layout on the bottom and then setting the alignment. (Just guessing.)

Comment: I have tryed that :/ since Im gonna deal with a lot of instances of That layout

Comment: Isn't `mostbottom`intended to be used together with left/right aligned controls? Anyway, when you create the new control. If you set the position to be above the layout you want at the bottom, then it should remain at the bottom.

Comment: nop what Im trying to do is that each time I create an instnace of that layout which contains some controls , it should be placed always in the bottom of the scroll box ^^